# Wrong output plot image in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to write simple program into Matlab but having problems with it. Task is:

> Draw output voltage magnitude and phase for schema shown on figure 1.
>   Let L be R2C/m, and let m is taking values from 1 to 5 in steps 0.2.

I tried with this code:

```
function coherence_task2 (R, omega, tau, m, i)


R=1;

tau=1;

f=50; 

omega=2*pi*f;

ksi=0;

i=1;

for m=1:0.2:5;

    moduo_Z=R*sqrt(((1+omega.^2*tau.^2)/((1-omega.^2*tau^2*m).^2+(omega*tau*m).^2)));

    argument_Z=(atan(omega*tau))-(atan((omega*tau*m)/(1-omega.^2*tau.^2*m)));

end;

Z=moduo_Z*exp((sqrt(-1))*argument_Z);

u=Z*i;

plot(moduo_z , argument_z)
```

Problem is this program plots just one single point. I am newbie to Matlab programming but want to learn..
For me biggest problem is I don't know what to plot on x axis, what on y axis. Could someone help me with this problem?
I don't want you to solve me whole code, just to give me path where to go.

EDIT:
Here is figure for this task:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how much this helps but I have a few quick pointers.

```
plot(moduo_z , argument_z)
```

moduo_z and argument_z are two single values not arrays of data to plot. If you want to add the the plot command into the for-loop you can use

```
hold on;
```

infront of the loop. Then all plot commands are drawn into the same graph. I modified your code a little, hopefully it helps.

```
function coherence_task2 (R, omega, tau, m, i)

R=1;
tau=1;
f=50; 
omega=2*pi*f;
ksi=0;
i=1;


moduo = zeros(21,1); % length(1:0.2:5) = 21.

argu = zeros(21,1);

cnt = 1;

for m=1:0.2:5

    moduo(cnt) = R*sqrt(((1+omega.^2*tau.^2)/((1-omega.^2*tau^2*m).^2+(omega*tau*m).^2)));

    argu(cnt) = (atan(omega*tau))-(atan((omega*tau*m)/(1-omega.^2*tau.^2*m))); 

    cnt = cnt + 1;

end

% This was never used

% Z=moduo_Z*exp((sqrt(-1))*argument_Z); 


% This was never used

% u=Z*i; 

plot(moduo , argu)
```

Comment: Obviously I have two problems. One is technical issue (problem with arrays), second misunderstanding of task (I don't know what to plot on x axis what on y axis). I am able to solve first task, but second is problem. I know that y axis should be voltage magnitude, but what is on x axis. As I can see only variable here could be frequency.

Answer (score 1):

the way matlab's plot function draws data tuplets (x,y) into a graph. That means you have to generate those tuplets, or x-y-value-pairs, first. For example like this:

```
% generate a vector of values from -5 to +5
x = [-5:0.1:5]; 

% put every element of x in the expression -> y has same length
y = 1 ./ (1 + exp(x));

% plot the two vectors. note that the tuplets are defined by the array index
plot(x,y)
```

Also, note that there are two kinds of ways to use an '.m' file (matlab scripts):

**Functions:** If your file starts with the keyword `function`, the file name must correspond to that function's name. This then makes the function available in your workspace, like a static method in C++ or Java - so in your case you can call your function `coherence_task2 (R, omega, tau, m, i)` from the console like this: `coherence_task2(123,44,55,66)`.

Also, your function now does not have a return argument. You can define a return argument in the .m file (first line): `function y = SomeFunctionName(x)`. In the function body, simply assign a value to y before 'endfunction' - this value is then automatically returned after execution. This allows you to call your function like this from the console and grab the result: `anotherY = SomeFunctionName(x)`.

**Batch file:** If the file doesnt start with `function`, it is interpreted as just a sequence of commands executed in your workspace - as if you would type them in the console. For example you could put what I wrote above (plot example) into an .m file. You can then execute the script/sequence by writing the filename into the console (without any arguments).

Here's an example of a batch file I wrote some days ago, which also illustrates that you don't plot functions, you plot x-y-value pairs:

```
n = [1:6000];

theta = 2*pi/(137.51/180) * n;
r = 0.1*sqrt(n);

x = cos(theta).*r;
y = sin(theta).*r;
plot(x, y, '.');
```

Comment: Thanks for great answer, you cleared me a lot of things. I am Java developer I Matlab is little different in syntax.